# compile error in generic class

Tags: java, generics

why following code doesn't compile ?

```
class aa1 <String> {
public void fun(){
String s = ""; // not compiling
}
}
class aa2 <String> {
String s = "";  // not compiling
}
class aa3 <String> {
String s = (String)""; // compiling
}
```

can some tell or give me link for this
thanks.

Comment: Doesn't the compiler error message you are getting give you some hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generic parameter  "String" hides the java.lang.String in this case.

in the class, if you declare the string s and specify its data type as "java.lang.String" then compiler won't complain.

```
public class aa<String> {

    java.lang.String s = "" ;

}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you may have misconstrued the idea behind generics.  The point is that your class (`aa`, in this case) can be... well, generic.  It's not of one fixed type, but rather can be any number of types through polymorphism.  The generic type is similar to a variable name, but it represents a class, rather than an instance of a class.  You could do something like:

```
class aa <T> {
    public void fun(T myObject){
        T s = myObject;
    }
}
```

This is an appropriate use of generics.  `T` just represents "some class".  **The reason the example you posted didn't compile because you overrode the visibility of String** (making it the generic type, rather than `java.lang.String`).  If you don't want it to be *any* class, but some subset of classes, you can do something like:

```
class aa <T extends MyInterface> {
    public void fun(T myObject){
        T s = myObject;
    }
}
```

In this case, you're guaranteed that instances of class `T` also extend the interface `MyInterface`.  However, you cannot extend `String`, since it's final.  If all you wanted was for the `String` object to be set, you do not need generics at all:

```
class aa {
    public void fun(){
        String s = "";
    }
}
```

---

*For more information about generics, read over [the Java tutorials on generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).*

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes no sense - the  declaration makes no sense - what are you really trying to do here?

The reason you're having issues compiling is that you're making a generics declaration that's hiding the JDK's java.lang.String.

You're also declaring the same class 3 times. Something like this would compile, but still probably doesn't achieve what you want.

```
class aa<NotString> {
    public void fun() {
        String s = ""; // compiles
    }
}

class aa2<NotString> {
    String s = "";  // compiles
}

class aa3<NotString> {
    String s = (String) ""; // compiling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that your generic parameter name (`String`) hides the `java.lang.String` type.

I would recommend renaming your generic parameter. By the way, which type do you want your `s` to be: `java.lang.String` or the same as the parameter? In the latter case, how cuold the compiler assign `""` (which is of type `java.lang.String`) to the potentially irrelevant type represented by the generic parameter?

Answer (score 0):

In your example you are declaring `String` as an identifier. You must not use keywords or type names. ([Generics Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)).

Comment: but it is compiling with casting in third class ?

Comment: @user460293 - It will compile with warning. Read that warning and you will get correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're declaring the generic type `String`, that will override the default `java.lang.String` type, your code is like typing:

```
class aa<T> {
    T s = "";
}
```

`T` is simply `Object` after type erasure, but since it can be initialized with anything (for example `Integer`), the compiler won't let you assign `String`s to it.